# We can’t parse this SQL syntax shows up in AWS Quicksight after applying toString()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a calculated field which computes a total based on a particular type:
`sumIf(amount, type = "sale")`

Now I'm trying to convert the result to string and then concatenate some text to it, but doing `toString(sumIf(amount, type = "sale"))` gives the following message:

> We can’t parse this SQL syntax. If you are using custom SQL, verify the syntax and try again. Otherwise, contact support.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the correct bracket type? i.e.

```
toString(sumIf({amount}, {type} = "sale"))
```

I tried an example like this and that worked fine, Quicksight can have issues when calling fields without the right brackets.

Comment: I tried and it shows the same message. Also, those brackets are removed automatically when I try to remove the calculated field